# ld: library not found for -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib

Tags: macos, qt, opencv

Getting “ld: library not found for -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib:

```
11:27:44: Running steps for project Hello_OpenCV...
11:27:44: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:27:44: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/Frameworks -o Hello_OpenCV main.o   -L/usr/local/lib -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_ml.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_objdetect.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_shape.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_stitching.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_superres.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videostab.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_calib3d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_features2d.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_highgui.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_videoio.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_video.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_photo.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_imgproc.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_flann.3.3.1.dylib -llibopencv_core.3.3.1.dylib 

ld: library not found for -llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Hello_OpenCV] Error 1
11:27:44: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Hello_OpenCV (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
11:27:44: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Comment: My Working envoiremente:
- macOS Sierra Ver. 10.12.6
- Qt Creator 4.4.1,  based on Qt 5.9.2 (Clang 7.0(Apple), 64 bit)
- OpenCV VERSION 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have OpenCV installed on your system? If you run the following command, do you get any output?

```
find / -name "*libopencv*" 2>/dev/null
```

If not, you probably need to ensure you install it first. Follow instructions such as the ones found [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/).

If the above does return something (example: `/path/to/lib/libopencv_dnn.3.3.1dylib`), then try adding `-L/path/to/lib` into your compile line

Comment: Just to complete your answer, maybe he have it installed, but missed the build_dnn flag in the CMAKE step (I think this module does not come by default)

Comment: Tks your support:

Comment: Tks your support: with your cmd find, I can get a long path list of all opencv ... At /usr/local/lib I can find also all opencv lib ... even adding -L/usr/local/lib into compile line . . . still the error . . .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're including the entire suite of OpenCV modules, some of which are very feature-specific and likely not needed if you have a simple application. The DNN module in particular is not included in binary form with OpenCV ([see this page on the matter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/tutorial_dnn_build.html)). If you're sure you need it, you need to compile it yourself.

If you aren't doing any machine learning, you likely don't need the library and you can remove `-llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib` from your compile line.

Comment: Tks. Ben. To generate opencv 3.3.0 I did use CMake 3.10 and acepted the defaut Configuration. I did remove llibopencv_dnn.3.3.1.dylib from compilar (file: lib /pkgconfig/opencv.pc) but the problem still, now with the next library -llibopencv_ml.3.3.1.dylib . . . and so on if I delete the next . . .

Comment: There are likely very few OpenCV libs you need to include. In most of my projects I have only needed core, imgproc, imgcodecs, and highgui. You can figure out which ones you need based on which headers you include. `#include opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp` means you need imgcodecs, for example.